# can i use ternary operator in className of div?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

can i do the following?

```
  <div className={`${customerDetails.isCustomer} ? u-pb--sm : u-ph--sm u-pb--sm`}>
```

If not what is the best way to write this?

Thanks

Comment: Please include your whole rendering method, including the definition of `customerDetails`.

Comment: @Nick.S. Maybe because both parts have `u-pb--sm` class?

Comment: styled-components is a library that allows styles to be defined as components. https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components

Answer (score 0):

That should work. Check `customerDetails` and try to `console.log` it.

```js
const CustomerDetails = ({ customerDetails }) =>
  <div className={customerDetails.isCustomer ? 'customer': 'notCustomer'}>
    {`Customer: ${customerDetails.isCustomer}`}
  </div>

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const customerDetails1 = { isCustomer: true }
    const customerDetails2 = { isCustomer: false }
    
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomerDetails customerDetails={customerDetails1} />
        <CustomerDetails customerDetails={customerDetails2} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```css
.customer {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.notCustomer {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works. I use it all the time. As others have asked, what does your render function look like? The true way of calling the render function again (incorporating changes in your DOM) is using `this.setState`. If you use a `this.state.something` as your ternary boolean, your className will dynamically update every single time you change it using `this.setState`.